# Should compounded words through agglutination be treated as unigrams or n-grams?

Tags: computational-linguistics, compounds, language-models

In a statistical language model, should one tokenize compounded words through agglutination as words by themselves (unigrams) or should they be tokenized into n-grams?

Example:

1. *Staatspolizei* (ISO 639-1: **de**) :
   a. unigram: staatspolizei
   b. ngram (bigram): (*stāt*, *polizei*).
2. *Purushottama* (ISO 639-1: **hi**)
   a. unigram: purushottama
   b. ngram (bigram): (*purusha*, *uttama*).

Which of the modeling (**a** or **b**) is linguistically proper (will yield a better language model)?

Comment: What do you mean "should"? Why does it matter?

Comment: I plead to leave this question open, it is frequent enough in corpus linguistics (and different linguists have different opinions on the answer, but this does not make it an "opinion based" question, IMO).

Comment: purushottam is nearly exclusively used for the Hindu god Rama, while purush + uttam can be any man

Comment: @jknappen: Thank you for your support. I am unsure why this question has the risk of being closed as an "opinion based" question as this is a hot research topic. For reference, here is the same question with very interesting answers:  https://www.quora.com/Should-compounded-words-through-agglutination-be-treated-as-unigrams-or-n-grams

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I don't have much background in linguistics)

I think - *if you are relating to agglutinantive and not polysynthetic languges* - it would depend on **what** you are trying to build and the **language** too.

But,

Staatspolizei (Secret State Police) may occur around words like-

*The* (whereas polizei would require and adjective before e.g. The Secret-State-Police vs The secret Police),

*found* (... Staatspolizei found and staats polizei found **can** have ambiguous interpretations if the language allows it, *XYZ found something* and *XYZ found by me*)

*etc.*

changing it's use totally.

whereas purushottama (man + ultimate/best/ideal = ideal man) is as you can see a compound of Noun + Adj. in that order, in Hindi , Sanskrit and other languages where it might be used *purush uttama asti* (please ignore grammatical/morphological endings if wrong) and *purushottama asti* **have** different meanings; *The man is ideal* and *The ideal man (is) exists*.

also *purush uttama karya karta hai* and *purushottam karya karta hai* mean *The man does the best work* and *The ideal man does work* respectively (The Adj. might be used to modify verb occuring in the same position)

The above distinctions thus, show that treating them as **unigrams** would be *better* than treating them as n-grams as far as the **semantic** role is concerned.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

For parsing: if the word is already in your 'dictionary' then treat it as a 'unigram'; but if it is new to you then treat it as an 'ngram'.  If you are doing semantic statistics on a corpus then you may need to do both.